# How to access a value of a dynamically named field in React using Redux Forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Here is a little background on what I'm trying to do. When the user clicks on add trip, I am using Redux Form Field Arrays to create fields.[image: Image #1]

The problem I am facing is that I want the form in the field array to change based on what option the user selects for the trip type (Point-to-Point, Local Transportation). So, I followed an example off of the Redux Form API website for [Selecting Form Values](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/selectingFormValues/). This did not work for me because the field names are dynamic and I have no idea on how to do this with the dynamic field names. Here is the code I've tried and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code for service type radio buttons:

```
<fieldset className="row">
   <div className="col">
      <Field name={`${member}.serviceType`} className="with-gap" component="input" type="radio" value="Point" id="trip1_choice1"/>
      <label htmlFor="trip1_choice1">
      Point-to-Point
      </label>
   </div>
   <div className="col">
      <Field name={`${member}.serviceType`}  className="with-gap" component="input" type="radio" value="Local" id="trip1_choice2" />
      <label htmlFor="trip1_choice2">
      Local Transport
      </label>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Code for changing forms based on which radio button is selected:

```
{[`${member}.serviceType`] === "Point" &&
  //HTML Form Code goes here
}
```

As you can see I'm having trouble with accessing the value of the dynamic field array. [`${member}.serviceType`] does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem here is an [example on github](https://gist.github.com/erikras/43a60a4adade000254b3f284339d7548) of how it should be done.

The following is the code I implemented.
This shows how I was able to get a specific value and it also shows how you can get all the values of the dynamic form.

```
// Get values from form
const selector2 = getFormValues('wizard');
const selector = formValueSelector("wizard");
Member = connect((state, props) => ({
  serviceTypeDyno: selector(state, `${props.member}.serviceType`),
  formValuesDyno: selector2(state)
}))(Member);
```

The if statement would then be:

```
{serviceTypeDyno === "Point" && (
  //HTML Form Code goes here
)}
```

If you're using getFormValues Selector:

```
{formValuesDyno.serviceType === "Point" && (
  //HTML Form Code goes here
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ref's](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), ejem.

```
<Field ref='fieldName' name={`${member}.serviceType`} className="with-gap" component="input" type="radio" value="Point" id="trip1_choice1"/>
```

To access them use: `this.refs.fieldName.getRenderedComponent().refs.input`

Check this issue [#1933](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1933) on redux-form repository

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've looked into what you said and added the `ref='fieldName'` to the Field and I've also added `withRef="true"`. I've also change the following check to this `{this.refs.fieldName.getRenderedComponent().refs.input === "Point" &&`. Now I'm getting an error saying **TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined**. Am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: @rohit563 try with `this.refs.['fieldName'].getRenderedComponent().refs.input`

Comment: @rohit563 and debug yours references in same component